# Using Moles with DateTime

Tags: unit-testing, moles, pex-and-moles

I'm starting to using Moles in unit tests and am struggling a little with documentation.

I want to mole DateTime.Now.

If you look around the old way of doing this was to add a reference to mscorlib, then add a stubx file for it (Add New Item -> Stubs And Moles For Testing).

The 'Stubs and Moles for Testing' template has been deprecated, instead all you need do is to right click a reference and select 'Add moles assembly', whch is fine.

VS2010 does not allow you to add a reference directly to mscorlib, because we have a reference to "System", this is ok as I can see DateTime in object browser as part of this namespace.

If I add a moles assembly for the System reference and rebuild I still can't resolve an MDateTime.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For Moles of mscorlib, you need to right-click directly on the References of your test project. You will have **Add Moles Assembly for mscorlib**.
Then, add `using System.Moles;`to your test class because you want Moles of System.DateTime (actually, you need a little more).

```
[TestMethod()]
[HostType("Moles")]
public void DateTimeMolesTest()
{
    DateTime date = new System.DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    MDateTime.NowGet = () => date;
    Assert.AreEqual(date, DateTime.Now);
}
```

If you run this test, it will fail because you need to add:

```
using Microsoft.Moles.Framework;
[assembly: MoledType(typeof(System.DateTime))]
```

Then, your test will succeed.
Don't forget that Moles cannot be used with some special types of mscorlib.

Comment: I tried the "Add Moles Assembly for mscorlib", but when building it gave me thousands of errors. Most are type/namespace resolve error because of lack of assembly reference. Any idea?

Comment: That's a damn nice answer +1