# Simulate 10min in nunit test

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I'm testing domain service. On unit test I'm locking user account after 10 invalid login attempts. User locktime is 10 minutes and after that valid login attemp should pass.

My question is how can I simulate passed 10min time in nunit test?

```
[Test]
...
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    service.Login(user, "badpassword");
    // lockuser for 10 min (inside Login method)
}
// wait 10min and try to login
```

Comment: Without knowing your implementation of "How do you block" how can we help? How do you know 10 mins passed? Using `DateTime.Now`?

Comment: You can pass the lockout-value as a parameter, so you can have your unit test test the behaviour using 2 seconds instead of 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really want to lock your tests for 10 minutes. The aim is to have the tests run as fast as possible, and you don't want a single test just waiting for 10 minutes.

The ideal way would be make your code *think* that 10 minutes have passed, or make your code wait for a shorter while when running tests. How you do that is going to depend on your implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You could fake the results of `DateTime.Now` with the [Moles framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798506.aspx). See [Using Moles with DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961982/using-moles-with-datetime) for an example.